# iFrame with data-url resize

Tags: html, css, iframe

Say I have a website which for example has the following CSS class:

```
div { border: red; }
```

And I would like to display e-mail's stored in a database somewhere on the same page with the CSS class. The e-mail has the following HTML:

```
<div style='height: 500px; background-color: red;'>Hello, I am an e-mail!</div>
```

Showing that HTML on my webpage will give it a red border. I would like the e-mail's HTML & CSS not be affected by the already present CSS, therefore I use an iframe in the following way:

```
<iframe 
    src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<div style='height: 500px; background-color: red;'>Hello, I am an e-mail!</div>"          
></iframe>
```

This works fine, however the iFrame is not responsive to the size of the e-mail (500px in the example). Therefore I add the following property:

```
onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;"
```

This works perfectly when I request a webpage on the same domain. However the way I am using it now I receive the following error:

[image]

I am not requesting any data from another origin, could someone please explain me why this is happening and if there is a workaround?

Comment: is your concern is to add an unique style to the desired tag and to prevent other pages styles to affect it? @TimNode

Comment: I have updated my question for clarity

Comment: "I am not requesting any data from another origin," — Two URLs are on different origins unless their scheme, hostname and port number match. `data:` and `http:` are not the same scheme.